# Replace variable products price range with "From:" + lowest price in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, price

In WooCommerce when a Variable product has variations with different prices it displays a price range with 2 amounts: For example 89.00 - 109.00.

I'd like to change it, displaying only "From: " and the lowest price like for example `From: 89.00` (removing the Max price). 
*("Fra: " means from in my language, just to clarify).*

Here is the code that I have tried:

```
// Main Price
$prices = array( $product->get_variation_price( 'min', true ), $product->get_variation_price( 'max', true ) );
$price = $prices[0] !== $prices[1] ? sprintf( __( 'Fra: %1$s', 'woocommerce' ), wc_price( $prices[0] ) ) : wc_price( $prices[0] );

// Sale Price
$prices = array( $product->get_variation_regular_price( 'min', true ), $product->get_variation_regular_price( 'max', true ) );
sort( $prices );
$saleprice = $prices[0] !== $prices[1] ? sprintf( __( 'Fra: %1$s', 'woocommerce' ), wc_price( $prices[0] ) ) : wc_price( $prices[0] );

if ( $price !== $saleprice ) {
$price = '<del>' . $saleprice . $product->get_price_suffix() . '</del> <ins>' . $price . $product->get_price_suffix() . '</ins>';
}
return $price;
}
```

This code doesn't work. Whenever I add it nothing happens.

What do I need to change, to get "From: " + the Min price instead?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*Your code is a bit incomplete as the hook and the function are missing…*

Here is the correct way to make it works for your variable products:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'change_variable_products_price_display', 10, 2 );
function change_variable_products_price_display( $price, $product ) {

    // Only for variable products type
    if( ! $product->is_type('variable') ) return $price;

    $prices = $product->get_variation_prices( true );

    if ( empty( $prices['price'] ) )
        return apply_filters( 'woocommerce_variable_empty_price_html', '', $product );

    $min_price = current( $prices['price'] );
    $max_price = end( $prices['price'] );
    $prefix_html = '<span class="price-prefix">' . __('Fra: ') . '</span>';

    $prefix = $min_price !== $max_price ? $prefix_html : ''; // HERE the prefix

    return apply_filters( 'woocommerce_variable_price_html', $prefix . wc_price( $min_price ) . $product->get_price_suffix(), $product );
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

Tested and works.

Comment: Ahh that makes great sense. That did indeed work, amazing. I will mark you as resolving the problem. One question though, is it possible to style the "Fra" (from text). It is in my case a lot smaller than the actual price and in a gray faded color. It doesn't seem to have an ID by it self so I cannot do it with CSS.

Comment: Of course, I am so sorry for not doing that already. Hereby marked. Thank you

Comment: But when a product is on sale, only the sale price is visible, not the original price, any way of keeping that too?

Comment: You can check if the product is on sale, and then don't do anything, as sale products only will show the lowest price already.
````if( ! $product->is_type('variable') || $product->is_on_sale() ) return $price;````